# How to get the value of a dynamic and multi-update id with jQuery and Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need help with several things:

First, I want to know how to get the id of an input, if it comes dynamically from the database. In the html it shows me for example for `field 1 -> id = "parameter1"`, for `field 2 -> id = "parameter2"`

```
<input id='parametro"+ index.id +"' value='" + index.id + "'></input>
```

This is the jQuery code to fetch all the elements from the table and display them in the html. Second we have the update button, what you have to do is grab the data and update them all together, I know that I must do a forEach to do all the updates, but I don't know how to do it or where to accommodate it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function getParametros() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/slim/apiParametros.php/db_parametros",
            type: "get",
            success: function (response) {
                $(".primerSemestre").html('');
                $(".segundoSemestre").html('');
                $.each(JSON.parse(response), function (i, index) {
                        
                    if (index.id <= 6) {
                        $(".primerSemestre").append("<div class='input-group'>" +
                        "<input id='parametro"+ index.id +"' value='" + index.id + "' hidden></input>"+
                        "<div id='parametro"+ index.mes +"' class='input-group-prepend' style='flex:0 0 20%'><span class='input-group-text w-100'>" + index.mes + "</span></div>" +
                        "<input type='number' id='parametro"+ index.valor +"' class='form-control' value='" + index.valor + "'>" +
                        "</div><br>");
                    }
                    if (index.id > 6) {
                        $(".segundoSemestre").append("<div class='input-group'>" +
                        "<input id='parametro"+ index.id +"' value='" + index.id + "' hidden></input>"+
                        "<div id='parametro"+ index.mes +"' class='input-group-append' style='flex:0 0 20%'><span class='input-group-text w-100'>" + index.mes + "</span></div>" +
                        "<input type='number' id='parametro"+ index.valor +"' class='form-control' value='" + index.valor + "'>" +
                        "</div><br>");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
    getParametros();

        $("#btnGuardar").click(function () {
            var id = $('#parametro'+'2').val();
            console.log(id)
            var mes = $('#parametro'+'Febrero').text();
            console.log(mes)
            var valor = $('#parametro'+'20').val();
            console.log(valor)
            
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost/slim/apiParametros.php/db_parametros/" + id,
                type: "put",
                data: { id: id, mes: mes, valor: valor },
                success: function () {

                    getParametros();
                }
            });
            
        });
});
```

Comment: Is your goal to generate `<input>` elements based on database values and then submit edited values to update the database?

Comment: @showdev I bring the values ​​from the database and put together two columns. Then I need that if I change one data or several, this data is saved in the database, but I need to do it in a multiple way. The only data I need to change is the value, the rest always remains the same.

Comment: What is `btnGuardar` in your code ? Also , where are you getting these values `field 1 -> id..` ?

Comment: @Swati The `btnGuardar` is a button that all you have to do is send the changed data to the database and update them, the values ​​of (field 1 -> id ..) is an example, when I bring each record, it comes with its corresponding id, which comes dynamically, because it is a concatenation of a string + variable `(id = 'parameter "+ index.id +"')` and what I want to know is how to access that variable from `btnGuardar` dynamic

Comment: Hi, did you tried below answer ?

Answer (score 0):

store data in JSON > when function fires > update values as per Key and values

Answer (score 0):

You can add `class` to each inputs then it would be easy to identify them . So , whenever your `btnGuardar` is clicked you can simply use `.each` to iterate through your inputs and then get values of input using `$(this).find(".yourclassname").val()` and pass this to your backend

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//suppose this is return from ajax..
var response = [{
  "id": 1,
  "mes": "acb",
  "valor": 1
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "mes": "acb2",
  "valor": 2
}, {
  "id": 8,
  "mes": "acb8",
  "valor": 8
}, {
  "id": 9,
  "mes": "acb9",
  "valor": 9
}]

function getParametros() {
  /* $.ajax({
     url: "http://localhost/slim/apiParametros.php/db_parametros",
     type: "get",
     success: function(response) {
       $(".primerSemestre").html('');
       $(".segundoSemestre").html('');*/
  $.each(response, function(i, index) {

    if (index.id <= 6) {
      //added class
      $(".primerSemestre").append("<div class='input-group'>" +
        "<input id='parametro" + index.id + "' class='id' value='" + index.id + "' hidden></input>" +
        "<div id='parametro" + index.mes + "' class='input-group-prepend mes' style='flex:0 0 20%'><span class='input-group-text w-100'>" + index.mes + "</span></div>" +
        "<input type='number' id='parametro" + index.valor + "' class='form-control valor' value='" + index.valor + "'>" +
        "</div><br>");
    }
    if (index.id > 6) {
      //added class
      $(".segundoSemestre").append("<div class='input-group'>" +
        "<input id='parametro" + index.id + "' class='id' value='" + index.id + "' hidden></input>" +
        "<div id='parametro" + index.mes + "' class='input-group-append' style='flex:0 0 20%'><span class='input-group-text w-100 mes'>" + index.mes + "</span></div>" +
        "<input type='number' id='parametro" + index.valor + "' class='form-control valor' value='" + index.valor + "'>" +
        "</div><br>");
    }
  });
  /*}
  });*/
}
getParametros();

$("#btnGuardar").click(function() {
  var datas = []
  //loop through input-group
  $(".input-group").each(function() {
    //get all valeus and add them inside json-array
    datas.push({
      "id": $(this).find(".id").val(),
      "mes": $(this).find(".mes").text(),
      "valor": $(this).find(".valor").val(),
    })
  })
  console.log(datas)
  //use json stringfy and send..them..via ajx
  //or : 
  /*  $(".input-group").each(function() {
          $.ajax({
              url: "http://localhost/slim/apiParametros.php/db_parametros/" + $(this).find(".id").val(),
              type: "put",
              data: {
                id: $(this).find(".id").val(),
                mes: $(this).find(".mes").text(),
                valor: $(this).find(".valor").val()
                },
                success: function() {

                  getParametros();
                }
              });

  })*/


});
```

```css
.primerSemestre,
.segundoSemestre {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="primerSemestre">
</div>
<div class="segundoSemestre">
</div>
<button id="btnGuardar">Save</button>
```